# How to cast list of object into derived collection class object

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, linq

**How can i cast them after apply linq to CollectionOfA object:**

```
CollectionOfA obj = GetDataFromService();
obj= obj.OrderBy(x=>x.Name).ToList();
```

**Here it gives compiler error cannot convert to implicit type on above line from Generic List to CollectionOfA.**

Here is my classes:

```
public class A{
public int Id {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class CollectionOfA: List<A>{
}
```

Comment: It's very rarely appropriate to inherit from `List`.  You should almost certainly be using composition here, not inheritance.

Comment: This is one of the reasons why you should never inherit from `List<T>`. Instead of your class `CollectionOfA`, just use `List<A>` everywhere. Or use an object of a class that contains a property of type `List<A>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ToList()` will not create a `CollectionOfA`. You could assign a `CollectionOfA` (i.e., the more derived class) to a `List<A>` (the less derived class) but not the other way round.

The way to go is to use the `Sort` method inherited from `List<T>`

```cs
obj.Sort((a, b) => a.Name.CompareTo(b.Name));
```

This also has the advantage to not allocate a new collection but to do an in-place sort.

---

Another option is to add a constructor to your collection class by inheriting the corresponding one form `List<T>`:

```cs
public class CollectionOfA : List<A>
{
    public CollectionOfA()
    {
    }

    public CollectionOfA(IEnumerable<A> collection) : base(collection)
    {
    }
}
```

Note that we also must add the default constructor to not break existing code.

We can the use it like this:

```cs
obj = new CollectionOfA(obj.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ThenBy(x => x.Id));
```